# Desktop stuck in alt-tab mode

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, application-switcher

I don't know how I managed to do this but my desktop is stuck in the alt-tab application selector mode. Clicking on an application does nothing, it stays on the zoomed out view.

Any tips on how I can escape this?

Things I have tried so far.

- Restarting computer, works initially then goes back to zoomed out mode when changing apps.
- Restarting lightdm.
- Using <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and other common keyboard shortcuts.

Cheers

**EDIT**

Seems to be a glitch with the mouse input, after rebooting a few times it seems to be back to normal.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is it? Is it up to date (updated & upgraded)? What happens when you click on the controls at the top right corner of the windows (iconize, fullscreen, and quit)?

Comment: It's the latest version 21.04, all software is up to date except the kernel package as I have a custom kernel. I don't seem to have those options in the top right. In my top right I have device related settings, bluetooth, wifi, power, brightness etc..

Comment: 1. OK, but I mean in each of the windows on the screen. Are there any controls there? 2. Which desktop environment is it (Ubuntu standard is Gnome)?

Comment: Yes it's gnome. There's no options on the individual windows, they just get a grey border around them when you hover over them, clicking on them does nothing

Comment: The alt-tab pop-up is different in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I will check with a live Ubuntu 21.04 system and come back to you.

Comment: I have just rebooted again and I get a different application switcher when pressing alt-tab.  This one seems to be working ok, so strange.

Comment: OK, maybe it was a temporary error. Please come back it it happens again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think it was actually some form of glitch with the mouse input. When I press SUPER + A now it takes me back to the screen I was originally stuck on but this time when I click on a window it opens that window.

Comment: It is a bug which I confirm, and you will see it back now and then. Was it an upgraded system or a fresh install? Mine is upgraded.

Comment: @sudodus OP most likely does not intended to refer to the Alt+Tab window, but to the application overview (as also appears from the screen shot). Saw this issue myself on a system upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04.

Comment: @vanadium, Yes, I understand now. (I could not resist testing it in a Ubuntu 21.04 system, and saw it - but it was not locked for me but responded to mouse clicks or touchpad clicks).

Comment: stuck power(windose)  key? probably not as clicking on an app would select it. but try different keyboard, disable laptop keyboard and use another usb keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but reading this question gave me a hint about issue with keyboard layout.

Here how I fix the issue for me:

1. Open Settings-> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Switch Windows of an Application.
   [image: Keyboard shortcut - Switch windows of an application]
2. Double click on the option and press BACKSPACE key
3. Press SET(SAVE).

All done. Now you can use Super key for switching windows.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred to me when i set an keyboard shortcut to launch File Explore. Once i removed that shortcut, the issue was gone. i'm not sure if there is any co-relation.